# SQLite менеджер

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Какие существуют варианты для просмотра и управления базой SQLite? Есть ли менеджеры как MSSQL manager?

Comment: Вам именно на Андроид нужно? Уточните.

Comment: На всякий случай для Большого Брата: http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, вот [sqliteonline](https://sqliteonline.com/).

Или вот [Sqlite Studio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt).

Comment: Я думаю, человеку нужно именно на Андроиде существующие БД просматривать/редактировать.

Comment: Вот удобная для android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lastempirestudio.sqliteprime&hl=ru